# apt-get install stuck in unmet dependencies loop

Tags: apt, software-installation

I tried to install monodevelop and it failed to install "msbuild":

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/msbuild_1%3a16.6+xamarinxplat.2020.04.29.14.43-0xamarin5+raspbian9b1_all.deb
```

Now, when I try to install anything, it complains about msbuild and aborts the install:

```
sudo apt-get install cc65
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 monodevelop : Depends: msbuild but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried the suggested `apt --fix-broken install`, and it looks like it is trying to reinstall `msbuild`, but it still fails. I've also tried [several other methods](https://net2.com/how-to-fix-unmet-dependencies-error-in-ubuntu/) without luck, including deleting the cached `*.deb` file.

How do I correct this loop?

Comment: Did you tried to remove the dependency and make an update?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to remove the `monodevelop` package; then `apt` will stop trying to satisfy its dependencies.

Alternatively, you can fix whatever caused `msbuild`’s installation to fail; there should have been error messages before the “Errors were encountered” message, explaining what those errors were.